# Authenticate WordPress login from External PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption

I'm building a C# application which user needs to login first and those login credentials will be same as WordPress login credentials. This is what I've done for now.

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['username']) || empty($_GET['password']) ) {
    echo "error";
}
else
{
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    try 
    {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wordpress", "root", "");
    } catch ( PDOException $e )
    {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = :username AND user_pass = :user_pass");
    $query->execute(array('username' => $_GET['username'], 'user_pass' => $password));
    $query = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ( $query )
    {
        echo "done";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}
?>
```

It's really hard to decrypt the WP password. How can I make a .php file which is going to check WP login correct or wrong?